# What is a word that means one-based index?

Tags: single-word-requests

As opposed to zero-based. This is in a context where *index* would certainly be interpreted as zero-based. Some possibilities: *count*, *number*, *numbering*, *ordinal*. But I'm not sure which of these, or another word altogether, would be the most clear.

*Count* also has the disadvantage of being easy to confuse with "number of entities inside or related to the referred entity" as opposed to "number of entities before the referred entity, plus one".

By way of explanation, in the following list [A, B, C, D, E], the zero-based index of C is 2, while the one-based index of C is 3.

Comment: What's wrong with "one-based index" ? see [zero-based numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering)

Comment: @Graffito, that would be unambiguous, but perhaps a little pedantic. I figured that in non-programming contexts there would have arisen in popular use a term to refer to the kind of indexing in popular use.

Comment: [Sequence number](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Sequence+number) : A number assigned to an item to indicate its relative position in a series of related items.

Comment: @Graffito That [appears to be an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-should-be-done-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-ins).

Comment: @AndrewLeach - The OP asked for a single word!

Comment: For what it's worth, I ended up using "number" as the title for a table column that displays one-based indices.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be consistent with technical terms used in math,

- For zero-based index: [*Nonnegative*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NonnegativeInteger.html) Index
- For one-based index: [*Positive*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PositiveInteger.html) Index